# Почему при положительной репутации все равно не дает отвечать?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, запрет-публикаций

Репутация положительная, нарушений не вижу, при этом все равно вижу:
"Ответы от этой учётной записи больше не принимаются. Подробнее в справочном центре."
Затер его до дыр, не вижу описание возможной причины.

Comment: Об этом сообщении есть [целая страница в справочном центре](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans). И имейте в виду, удалённые ответы (если они у вас есть или будут) тоже учитываются при расчёте.

Comment: В том то и дело, что эту целую страницу я перечитал вдоль и поперек. Там нет случая, который бы подходил к моему. Минусов нет, ответы с положительными отметками есть. Я разумный человек и спамом не занимался. Не вижу не единой причины.

Comment: Окей, тогда ждём модераторов. Пусть посмотрят.

Comment: Вот видите, минусы всё же есть.

Comment: Не понимаю откуда они. Странно. Все странно. Я имею запредельно высокую репутацию на аналогичном проекте "Тостер", Всегда отвечаю по делу. Думал буду полезен и здесь, но мягко говоря, устал биться головой об стену.

Answer (score 2):

## В чём причина

Есть три удалённых ответа, имеющих рейтинг -1. Вероятно, что дело в них.

Однако, блокировка сработала после публикации вопроса «https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/648459/181472» Возможно, этот вопрос понизил какой-то рассчитываемый системой показатель «положительного вклада»:

> Блокировка снимается системой автоматически, когда положительный вклад пользователя перевешивает отрицательный рейтинг предыдущих сообщений.

## Что теперь делать

- Доработайте уже опубликованные ответы, добавьте подробностей.
- Задайте пару [хороших](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), интересных вопросов [по теме сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Нет, блокировка была до этого. Решил создать какой-нибудь вопрос, что бы проверить.

Comment: И как делать вклад, если все заблокировано. Какой-то замкнутый круг. Удачи проекту, я наверное пойду в соседний (не буду делать рекламу).